# Getting a time difference in mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, time, unix-timestamp

I'm using PHP + mongoDB.

How can I get a time difference between two time values?

I have a real time value which is string

```
$realtime = "2010-01-01 12:00:00";
```

and another value which is unixstamp time,

```
$mongotime = new Mongodate(strtotime($realtime));
```

So I can use either a string time value or unix time stamp.

But I'm not sure the way to get time difference between two values.

Should I just subtract two $mongotime values and does it give me a time difference in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 unix timestamps...

```
$date  = $item['pubdate'];
(etc ...)
$unix_now = time();
$result = strtotime($date, $unix_now);
$unix_diff_min = (($unix_now  - $result) / 60);
$min = round($unix_diff_min);
```

This will give number of mins between the 2 timestamps...